How to Add Custom Field to API Requests in Airbyte?
I'm using Airbyte to extract data from Facebook Marketing. I need to add a custom field to the API requests to better manage the data extraction process. The main problem is that the returned campaigns data does not include a way to map the adsets to the campaigns, so i want to add the "adsets" field to the campaigns request to then map them.
I have reviewed Airbyte documentation and forums but couldn't find clear instructions. I have also tried to use the Custom Insights but no luck.
